# tracking memory usage or consumption for apache spark 2.0.2

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, memory-management, monitoring, apache-spark-2.0

I m beginner in apache spark and have installed a prebuilt distribution of apache spark with hadoop. I look to get the consumption or the usage of memory while running the example PageRank implemented within spark. I have my cluster standalone mode with 1 maser and 4 workers (Virtual machines)

I have tried external tools like ganglia and graphite but they give the memory usage at resource or system level (more general) but what i need exactly is "to track the behavior of the memory (Storage, execution) while running the algorithm does it means, memory usage for a spark application-ID ". Is there anyway to get it into text-file for further exploitation? Please help me on this, Thanks

Comment: is there a way to get the memory consumption for only storage ?